# How to use apollo codegen typescript types in code?

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo

The generated types are awesome but how am I supposed to use them? The nested fields of the results are interface joined by `_` so it feels wrong to import such a long type name...

In my code I have something like this...

```
export interface InterviewerHistory_viewer_interviews_edges_node {
  id: string;
  scheduledTime: string;
  interviewerId: string;
  intervieweeId: string | null;
  participants: (InterviewerHistory_viewer_interviews_edges_node_participants | null)[] | null;
  intervieweeReview: InterviewerHistory_viewer_interviews_edges_node_intervieweeReview | null;
}
```

If I wanted to run some function on some of these fields and I had to type the args, that would be very confusing and odd... Am I using this tool wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try downgrading your `apollo-codegen` version.

I had the same issue since I upgraded to `apollo-codegen 0.20.0`, so I downgraded to `0.19.0` and the interface names are a little bit better.

Comment: yeah id rather just stay current and deal with it but thanks fir the info